# MySQL: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a workflow in my application where an admin for an organization can add a user to their organization. Once a form submission, I first insert a new record into my user table with the users email and the organization id associated with the admin. After that user is created, a member record which connects the user to the organization is created with the users email and the users organization id and `user_id`. The issue I am running into is with creating a record on the member table with the recently created users `user_id`. While I have no issue storing the `organization_id` present, for some reason passing the `user_id` throws an error related to the foreign key:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`work`.`member`, CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`organization_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)]
```

Why can't I pass the user_id on record creation. Is it because the column is associated to a foreign key?

Here are the inserts:

**User insert (No error):**

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`,`email`,`organization_id`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'test+email@gmail.com','1','2016-06-07 11:51:54','2016-06-07 11:51:54');
```

**Member insert (Error with user_id):**

```
INSERT INTO `member` (`member_id`,`member_email`,`organization_id`,`user_id`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'test+email@gmail.com','1',8,'2016-06-07 11:51:54','2016-06-07 11:51:54');
```

**User Table:**

```
`user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentication_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_password_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_password_expires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Organization table:**

```
`organization` (
  `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organization_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`organization_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Member table:**

```
`member` (
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `member_email` (`member_email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `member_user_id_organizationId_unique` (`organization_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`organization_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What is the value of your user_id in your user table, after the insert?

Comment: @OP: Does the `organization_id` value `1` exists in table `organization` ?

Comment: `organization_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,` in table users seems to be a outdated by your linking table member and can be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem to me that you got your constraints mixed up.

I created the tables using your sql and reverse engineered with MySQLWorkbench to get an EER containing your tables.

[image]

On first sight you can see that organization_id in table organization is linked with user_id in members table.

If you change your constraints to the following, it will work:

```
CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `organization` (`organization_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Good observation. And still, user's insert on `member` lacks `organisation_id`

Comment: I assumed he has organization_id 1 already present in his table

Comment: I meant on OP's `insert` statement. I believe he did not include the correct `organization_id` value.

Comment: @DKSan thank you for all of the effort in trying to replicate my issue. This looks like it would resolve my issue, but I need to double check. To everyone who commented about the wrong `organization_id`, this is the correct value for the `organization_id` associated with the admin, but it looks like it is in string form, ``1``. This doesn't throw an error, but I'm assuming Mysql knows to parse it to integer since it is accepted?

Comment: @cphill i am glad i was able to help. The id as string is converted to integer format by the dbms. If you try with a non convertable string (for example 'abc') an error will occure

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_1` to this:

```
CONSTRAINT `member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES user(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```